# Portable chrome on gentoo

Tags: google-chrome-headless, gentoo

I'm currently building an module for Drupal 7, which requires the functionality of taking an screenshot of another website and delivering this to the user. For doing this i'm using an [php wrapper](https://github.com/chrome-php/headless-chromium-php) for chrome (headless).

Aaand: It works on my machine!

But: I realizied, that the project is hosted on a managed server, so i can't install the [google-chrome package](https://packages.gentoo.org/packages/www-client/google-chrome) from the gentoo-repository.

Now my questions is if there is any sort of portable chrome for this use case.

Thank your for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way i took was using an Amazon Lightsail Instance with an LAMP-Stack. There i could install the required parts. So i'm calling an endpoint on this instance from my drupal module and it's answers with the base64-encoded image data (and some stuff around it).